# Trouble with particle attraction using PVectors

Tags: vector, graphics, processing, particles

I'm making a particle-attractor-thing in Processing 3.0, and I'm having difficulty when adding multiples of what I've deemed 'Nodes'; objects that automatically attract or repel particles without mouse input. Normally left-clicking the mouse attracts these particles and right-clicking repels them. I made Nodes so that I could have multiple locations attracting/repelling at once.

The main problem I'm having atm is when I add more than one Node, only the last-added one actually works; all others do nothing.

Here is all my code including two other classes (Particle and Node). It's a lot of code, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could point out my error(s).

http://pastebin.com/iKELuVJ7

I believe the trouble is in the Particle class in the Node for loop where I am setting `acc = d`, but I don't know a good workaround.

As an additional question, does anyone know a good way to make the strength of the attraction scale inversely with distance from the attracting object? I tried a backwards `map()` function with arbitrary upper/lower limits which works for now, but I'd prefer not to hardcode it. Any other general improvements/recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend this website by Daniel Shiffman to you about [Gravitational Attraction](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-2-forces/#29-gravitational-attraction).

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice looking sketch. You are totally right about `acc = d`.
This part:

```
for (Node n: nodes) {
     PVector d = PVector.sub(n.loc, loc);
     d.normalize();
     d.mult(n.strength);
     acc = d;
    }
```

means you're overwriting the acc vector which d.
Since you run loop, in the end acc will be equal to the last node in your list.
If you want each node to have a certain influence, simply add the node based vector to `acc`:

```
for (Node n: nodes) {
     PVector d = PVector.sub(n.loc, loc);
     d.normalize();
     d.mult(n.strength);
     acc.add(d);
    }
```

You did this already on the mouse interaction.

In terms of other recommendations, you could try to cache PVector instances more often. Bellow I supply a basic example of how to cache the mousePosition (as a single top level variable, rather than multiple instances, per particle, per frame). `mag()` uses `sqrt()` which can be costly. Try using [magSq()](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_magSq_.html) instead (and using squared ranges instead). You can spot these this in [chapter 6.15 A Few Last Notes: Optimization Tricks of Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/) by Daniel Shiffman. I warmly recommend this book.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PVector m = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY); 

ArrayList<Particle> parts = new ArrayList<Particle>();
ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
float speed = 2;
float grav = 4;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  size(800, 800, P2D);
//  fullScreen(P2D);
  noStroke();
  smooth(4);
  blendMode(ADD);
  frameRate(60);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    parts.add(new Particle(new PVector(random(width), random(height)), (int)random(1, 25)));
  }
  nodes.add(new Node(new PVector(200, 400), 0.75));
  nodes.add(new Node(new PVector(400, 400), 0.50));
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void draw() {
  background(0);

  if(mousePressed){
    m.set(mouseX, mouseY);
  }

  for (Node n: nodes) {
    n.draw();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
     Particle p = (Particle) parts.get(i);
     p.draw();
     p.boundary();
  }
} 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Particle {
  PVector loc, vel, acc;
  int size = 5;

  Particle(PVector loc, int size) {
    this.loc = loc;
    vel = new PVector();
    acc = new PVector();
    this.size = size;
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  void draw() {
    acc.mult(0);

    for (Node n: nodes) {
     PVector d = PVector.sub(n.loc, loc);
     d.normalize();
     d.mult(n.strength);
     //acc = d;
     acc.add(d);
    }


    if (mousePressed && mouseButton == LEFT) {
      PVector d = PVector.sub(m, loc);
      //d.normalize();
      d.setMag(map(d.mag(), 0, 2200, speed, 0));
      d.mult(speed);
      //acc = d;
      acc.add(d);
    } else if (mousePressed && mouseButton == RIGHT) {
      PVector d = PVector.sub(m, loc);
      d.normalize();
      d.mult(-1*speed);
      //acc = d;
      acc.add(d);
    }

    acc.set(acc);
    acc.mult(acc.mag());
    vel.add(acc);
    //vel.add(new PVector(0, grav));
    loc.add(vel);
    acc.mult(0);
    //vel.mult(pow(0.90, 0.1*size));
    vel.mult(0.97);

    colorScheme(0);//"RedYellow"
    ellipse(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  void boundary() {
    if(loc.x < 0)
      vel.x *= -1;
    if(loc.x > width)
      vel.x *= -1;
    if(loc.y < 0)
      vel.y *= -1;
    if(loc.y > height)
      vel.y *= -1;
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 String[] patterns = {"RedYellow","RedMagenta","GreenYellow","GreenCyan","BlueMagenta","BlueCyan","Cyclic","BWCyclic","PROTOTYPE"};
  //void colorScheme(String pattern) {
  void colorScheme(int pattern) {
    //compute this once, rather than multiple times per case
    //also check out magSq() https://processing.org/reference/PVector_magSq_.html  
    float mag = vel.mag();
    switch (pattern) {
      case 0:
        fill(255, map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 255), map(mag - 20, 0, 20, 0, 255)); //Red Yellow White
        break;
      case 1:
        fill(255, map(mag - 20, 0, 20, 0, 255), map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 255)); //Red Magenta White
        break;
      case 2:
        fill(map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 255), 255, map(mag - 20, 0, 20, 0, 255)); //Green Yellow White
        break;
      case 3:
        fill(map(mag - 20, 0, 20, 0, 255), 255, map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 255)); //Green Cyan White
        break;
      case 4:
        fill(map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 255), map(mag - 20, 0, 20, 0, 255), 255); //Blue Magenta White
        break;
      case 5:
        fill(map(mag - 20, 0, 20, 0, 255), map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 255), 255); //Blue Cyan White
        break;
      case 6:
        fill(cos(map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 360))*255, cos(map(mag + 20/3, 0, 20, 0, 360))*255, cos(map(mag + 40/3, 0, 20, 0, 360))*255); //Cyclic
        break;
      case 7:
        fill(cos(map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 360))*255, cos(map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 360))*255, cos(map(mag, 0, 20, 0, 360))*255); //B&W Cyclic
        break;
      case 8:
        fill(0, 0, 0); //Cyclic
        break;
      default:
        stroke(255, 255, 255);
        fill(255, 255, 255);
        break;
    }
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Node {

  PVector loc;
  float strength;

  Node(PVector loc, float strength) {
    this.loc = loc;
    this.strength = strength;
  }

  void draw() {
    fill(255, 255, 255,64);
    ellipse(loc.x, loc.y, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

[image: particles 1]

[image: particles 2]

[image: particles 3]